# Navigating lisp

Tags: motion, sexp

I want to programmatically navigate emacs lisp (and similar "nested paren code").

Specific functions I want:

- Go to first child (which errors if there are no children (maybe `lispy-outline-goto-child` but better)
- Go to sibling
- Go to parent (already supported by `(backward-up-list)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out [Moving in the Parenthesis Structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html), specifically:

- <kbd>C-M-f</kbd>, which runs the command `forward-sexp`
- <kbd>C-M-b</kbd>, which runs the command `backward-sexp`
- <kbd>C-M-d</kbd>, which runs the command `down-list`

To get to the beginning of the 1st child, enter the list, then jump behind the 1st child and back to arrive at its beginning:
<kbd>C-M-d C-M-f C-M-b</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I'm completely aware of those functions, as far as I'm aware they don't address motion to the first child.

Comment: `forward-sexp` does not move to the next sibling but to the end of a sibling. It does however look like one can a "move to next sibling command" by calling `(progn (forward-sexp) (backward-sexp))`. So I guess the only think I'm after is *the first child*.

Comment: @AttRigh: see edit.

Comment: **enter the list by moving past**  might be more fiddly that one imagines, but it looks like `move-down` does this. So yep, `(progn (move-down) (forward-sexp) (backward-sexp))` goes to the first child (following your answer). Thanks for the help! The motions "child, parent, beginning-of-sibling, matching-bracket" seem somehow more natural to traverse the tree structure to me than `forward-sexp` `backward-sexp`.

Comment: +1. These are the commands I use, FWIW. Lately some Emacs users seem to prefer the more "structured-editing" approach of *smartparens*, *lispy*, and the like. Not I. That kind of editing was first introduced (to my knowledge) back in the 80s. I didn't like it then, and I don't like it now. At least when adopted for Emacs things are more flexible: you are not *locked into* having the code always have valid syntax at every moment. Editors that let you *only* perform editing operations that retain well-formedness or validity (e.g. wrt a schema or DTD) are too limiting, IMAO. (Tastes differ.)

Comment: Oops, I mean `(down-list)` rather than `(move-down)`